# No error or cout messages on cygwin console

Tags: c++, cygwin, iostream

I installed cygwin on my Windows7 machine, and I'm running some c++ code. When I'm running this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Pop.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {
  ifstream in;
  ofstream out;
  cout << "something";
  out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (out.is_open())
    out << "1\n";
  else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
  out.close();
  int seed = time(NULL);
  out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (out.is_open())
    out << "2\n";
  else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
  out.close();
  out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (out.is_open())
    out << "seed " << seed << '\n';
  else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
  out.close();
  out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (out.is_open())
    out << "3\n";
  else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
  out.close();
  srand (seed);
  out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (out.is_open())
    out << "4\n";
  else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
  out.close();
  double parameters[4];
  int location;
  in.open("input7.txt", ios::in);
  out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (out.is_open())
    out << "5\n";
  else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
  out.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I see an output on the console (something). But when I run my complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Pop.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {
  ifstream in;
  ofstream out;
  cout << "something";
  out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (out.is_open())
    out << "1\n";
  else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
  out.close();
  int seed = time(NULL);
  out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (out.is_open())
    out << "2\n";
  else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
  out.close();
  out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (out.is_open())
    out << "seed " << seed << '\n';
  else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
  out.close();
  out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (out.is_open())
    out << "3\n";
  else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
  out.close();
  srand (seed);
  out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (out.is_open())
    out << "4\n";
  else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
  out.close();
  double parameters[4];
  int location;
  in.open("input7.txt", ios::in);
  out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
  if (out.is_open())
    out << "5\n";
  else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
  out.close();
     if (in.is_open()) {
    out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
    if (out.is_open())
      out << "6\n";
    else
      cout << "unable to open res7 file";
    out.close();
    char line[256];
    while (!in.getline(line, 256).eof()) {
      out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
      if (out.is_open())
    out << "7\n";
      else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
      out.close();
      char *input = strtok(line, " ");
      int i=0;
      while (input!=NULL) {
    out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
    if (out.is_open())
      out << "8\n";
    else
      cout << "unable to open res7 file";
    out.close();
    parameters[i] = atof(input);
    input = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
      }
      int rnum = rand();
      location = rnum%10000;
      out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
      if (out.is_open())
    out << "9\n";
      else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
      out.close();
      Pop p(parameters[0], parameters[1], 0.2, 0.1, parameters[2], location);
      out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
      if (out.is_open())
    out << "10\n";
      else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
      out.close();
      double L = exp(-parameters[3]);
      double FF_mean = p.FF_steady(parameters[3], L, 0.0);
      out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
      if (out.is_open())
    out << "11\n";
      else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
      out.close();
      out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
      if (out.is_open()) {
    out << "number of chromosomes is " << p.all_population[0]->ga->chromosome << "  alpha is " << parameters[2] << "  cost is " << parameters[1];
    out << "  a is " << parameters[0] << "  u is " << parameters[3] << "  location is " << location << "  FF steady is " << FF_mean << '\n';
      }
      else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file FF";
      out.close();
      out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
      if (out.is_open())
    out << "12\n";
      else
    cout << "unable to open res7 file";
      out.close();
      if (FF_mean>0.1) {
    out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
    if (out.is_open())
      out << "13\n";
    else
      cout << "unable to open res7 file";
    out.close();
    p.insert_O(0.05);
    out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
    if (out.is_open())
      out << "14\n";
    else
      cout << "unable to open res7 file";
    out.close();
    double total_mean = p.steady(parameters[3], L, 0.0);
    double perc = p.perc_O();
    out.open("res7.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
    if (out.is_open())
      out << "total steady is " << total_mean << "   perc O is " << perc << '\n';
    else
      cout << "unable to open res7 file";
    out.close();
      }
    }
  }
  else
    cout << "Unable to open input7 file\n";
    in.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I don't see any output on the console. When I run the code on a different machine, I see that I have a floating point exception. I guess I could find where it is, but what I don't understand is why I don't see any output or the error on the console in cygwin. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Also, are you using the Cygwin gcc or something else?

Comment: `cout` is only called if there is a failure to open the "res7" file? Does the `printf()` work? Try adding `cout << "hello\n";` after `printf()` (basically somewhere it will always be called).

Comment: Can you try reducing the code down to a simple `cout << "Hello, world!"`?  The results of that test should help us.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the code compiles? At the third to last line you have

```
in.close();*/
```

However, there is no opening /* tag. I would make sure your code is actually compiling and you have a new .exe generated. You may be failing to compile and running an old .exe that does not have any cout's.

Also, are you sure there are no exceptions being thrown? I can not fully test the code because I am missing the source for "Pop.h", so I can not fully see what errors I get when I compile. Could you try to have an initial cout at the top of your program, and perhaps provide the soruce to Pop.h, so we may test it more.

Answer (score 0):

First, an exception may terminate a program without even giving information.  Cygwin is an attempt to combine windows and unix and things don't always work perfectly.

Second, `std::cout` is a buffered stream.  As such, each `operator<<` adds to the buffer until either the buffer fills and it is automatically output, you explicitly flush the buffer with `cout.flush()`, or implicitly flush the buffer such as `std::endl` will cause.

So, you need to use the debugger or the other system to find the bug and fix it.  You also need to test on multiple platforms as things do behave differently on differently -- including different errors and even appearing to work.